# Apple Sandbox and AXUIElementRefs

Tags: xcode, cocoa, sandbox

How can i access another app if my app is in this strange Sandboxing thing which is required to release a app in the MAC App Store?

I'm reading with this Method an UIElement:

```
AXUIElementCopyElementAtPosition(xxx)
```

This works fine so far. But if i enable App Sandboxing, i no longer get  reference to the MenuItem!!!

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Such Apis are not supported from within the sandbox. All you can do is file a radar and sell your app outside of the store

Answer (score 0):

Filed a bug... [radar: 12174743](https://bugreport.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/RadarWeb.woa/35/wo/0WFzopPdttnocJbUyUe11M/7.66)  **Keep filing Bugs** maybe someday they'll relent.

> *Flawed / illegal sandbox leads to failure of all Accesability API's,
>   aka AXUIElementRef's.*
>
> *Have you guys gone crazy over there???  Ever heard of the ADA act? 
>   Get ready to get sued..*
>
> *The sandbox is such a SAD result of your success.  It really pisses 
>   me off, actually.  It goes against every reason I have ever stood
>   behind this platform... through thick and thin.*